# How to Check if PowerShell is Ready?

Tags: c#, powershell, transition

I have a simple `Process.Start` command which takes `powershell` path as input

```
Process.Start(powerShellPath);
Thread.Sleep(5000); //wait till loading is done, typically a couple of seconds
```

But now I use `Thread.Sleep` to wait until the `powershell` is fully ready (by ready I mean as in: you can type/send something and it is responsive, but we can know this before we type/send anything to the `powershell`).

Is there any way to know if `powershell` is ready apart from waiting - that is, not by **time-based** logic but by **event-based** logic?

Comment: @PetSerAl I mean, as in not to put the process input idle or waiting for the input, but we know that the process is ready without any input.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish, or what your code will do next if/when you determine PowerShell is ready?

Comment: Once it is ready, I could get user input or write some strings on it (by the code) and the process would be smoothly noticeable: you can see string added, executed, see the result, etc... Just like how you will see human will interact with powershell

Comment: if you need to run a PS script from C# I would recommend you to use System.Management.Automation to setup a runspace using native C# methods, read the script file and then execute it. You'll have much more control over the whole process that way.

Comment: So you essentially want to run input and output through PowerShell to your Application and back out?

Comment: @Trondh Thanks for pointing out the tool which I can use (is it capable of checking by event-based?) It is an extra mile beyond the scope for my question actually. I will take a look how it works.

Comment: @AustinFrench If you what you mean is what I want to do after the powershell started, then the answer is yes. The problem I posted here, however, is more of how to detect the transition correctly and at the same time more smoothly.

Comment: You can setup separate eventhooks for errors, verbose logs, std out, etc. It's very rich.

Comment: @Trondh yes, I am exploring it right now. :) AddScript, AddParameters etc.. seems to be pretty powerful tool.

Answer (score -2):

You mean like this?

```
Start-Process powershellPath -NoNewWindow -Wait
```